# Delete request not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to put an "delele request" in my project but is not working...

Returns me this message:

> ""ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/produtos", ok: false, …}""

My method on service.ts is this:

```
 deleteProduct (productId: number): Observable<Product> {
      const url = `${this.produtosUrl}`;
      return this.http.delete<Product>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
          map((response: Response) => response.json())
 )

}
```

My component.ts:

```
  delete(productId: number): void {
  this.products = this.products.filter(Product => Product.id !== productId);

  this.produtoService.deleteProduct(productId).subscribe();
}
```

My method on node.js:

```
app.delete('/produtos', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    mc.query('DELETE FROM `produtos` WHERE `id`=?', [req.body.id], function 
(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.end('Record has been deleted!');
  });
 });
```

And, of course, html button:

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
      <th scope="row">{{product.id}}</th>
      <td>{{product.nome}}</td>
      <td>{{product.price}}</td>
      <td>{{product.url}}</td>
      <td> <button class="btn-primary delete" title="delete product"
        (click)="delete(product.id)">
        Delete
      </button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Glad if u could help me.

@Edit: projects on github =

https://github.com/Mauricio-vieira/Front-End-Project

https://github.com/Mauricio-vieira/Back-end-Project

Comment: Can you please post whole error code ?

Comment: The error is just this (getting from f12)
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/produtos", ok: false, …}

Comment: Can you check your network tab in developers tool, You probably had 403 error? It could be due to the CORS, mostly DELETE methods are not allowed in the request.

Comment: As per your error/Code it's tough to determine whats's the exact problem, Either provide some more information or ReProduce same error on some plunker or stackblitz

Comment: reqURL: http://localhost:8080/produtos
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 24
Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018 18:26:45 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YjI1ODAwMGE5ZWNmMTNiMTRjZGIyNzYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjkyNTc0Mjd9.6Wsv7MXLO9aQ1F1VR0WkXUhSuRn68c4O67dQCLualmc

Comment: I'll post on github the two projects (front and back)

Comment: Check the last edit, posted both projects on github

Answer (score 0):

In your Angular code, you are trying to parse the response:

```
map((response: Response) => response.json())
```

This will fail if the response is empty, as that is not valid JSON. Either remove this line, or change your backend to return some valid JSON

If you're using HttpClient, this will try to parse it as JSON by default, so removing that line will not fix it. As well as removing that line, you will need to set the `responseType` to `text` in your httpOptions:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  responseType: 'text' as 'text'
}
```

(Please note we have to explicitly type the responseType as per [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586). Also please note that there is no need to change the `Content-Type` header, as you're still sending JSON, just not getting JSON back.)

Comment: @MauricioRenan Are you using `Http` or `HttpClient` in Angular?

Comment: Yes, all these imports:

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators'

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json '})

}

Comment: @MauricioRenan Just updated the answer, please give that a go

Comment: I didn't understand... How can I change the response to text?

Comment: In the `httpOptions` object you need to add a property called `responseType` and set it to `"text"`

Comment: got this error: 
Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
const httpOptions: {
    headers: HttpHeaders;
    responseType: string;
}

Comment: Can you update your code with the change you've made please?

Comment: @MauricioRenan Updated the question for you

Comment: I've made the changes but still with this error: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: "text"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'

Comment: I can't reproduce, seems to compile fine in this Stackblitz... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gf8zrl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This stackblitz link is an empty project

Comment: Just resaved try again

Comment: Hmm, nice... But I'm still with the error :(
The code is this:
 deleteProduct (productId: number): Observable<Product> {
    const url = `${this.produtosUrl}`;
    return this.http.delete<Product>(url, httpOptions);


  }

Answer (score 0):

For delete requests you need to allow delete requests in the header.
Use res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");

Or add this middleware

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
    next()
}
```

If this header is not set delete request will not work on node.
Also you can do a post request to the required url and give delete functionality if none works. But setting the header works fine.

Comment: I have this on my code:
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
})
 But still not working

Comment: is req.body logging

Comment: What? Did not understand, sorry

Comment: you have a console.log so is req.body logging in your terminal

Comment: Oh, yes... Is not logging

Comment: That is because delete request is not being accesed. Browsers does not enable it by default. Instead of delete use app.post('/produtosDelete') as your route. Its just a quick fix